# Find mean of nth item in list of lists in Python

Tags: python, numpy, mean, nested-lists

after a lot of searching I haven't been able to find the answer to what seems like a simple question.

I have some code that is doing a Monte Carlo simulation and storing the results in a nested list. Here are the results I generate from a 10-trial simulation:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Where I'm stuck is I'd like to find the mean of the 0th item in each list, the 1st item, and so on. I generally use numpy.mean for this, but how do I instruct it to only average the nth item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.mean` with `axis=0`:

```
lst = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
np.mean(lst, axis=0)
# array([ 0.9,  1. ,  0.8,  0.9,  0.6,  0.8,  0.5,  0.7,  0.8,  0.5,  0.7, 0.5,  0.6])
```

Comment: That was easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question well, the answer is the same as @Psidom proposed but over `axis=1`. Also, you may need to convert it to a numpy array beforehand:

```
lst = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], # and so on...)
np.mean(lst, axis=1)
```